# FOR loop: pass 2 variables from a file simultaniously

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am writing shell script, to extract 2 variables from a file, and have used below FOR loop.

```
for i j in `cat list`
                do
                echo title
                echo total "$i" "," "$j"
                echo end
done
```

where cat list is

```
AAA 111
BBB 222
CCC 333
```

Getting error as `j' unexpected, I have used "while loop" but no luck.

expect output is

```
title
total AAA,111
total BBB,222
total CCC,333
end
```

Comment: What did your `while` loop look like?

Comment: That's zsh syntax, not bash syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, `while read`:

```
echo "title"
while read -r i j
do
    echo total "$i,$j"
done < list
echo "end"
```

It will give output:

```
title
total AAA,111
total BBB,222
total CCC,333
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A `for` or `while` loop actually isn't needed. Either of these `awk` commands will work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "title"}
           {print "total",$1","$2}
       END {print "end"}' list
```

or:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "title"}
           {printf "total %s,%s\n", $1, $2}
       END {print "end"}' list
```

The `BEGIN{print "title"}` prints the word `title` once, before the data in the file is read.

`{print "total",$1","$2}` prints the word `total` followed by an unquoted comma representing a space between the values in the columns columns and then the columns themselves.  This block is executed for each input line.

`END{print "end"}` prints the word `end` and the END of the file. END tells it to execute the block when the final input from the file has been read.

For the second command:

The only difference is:

`{printf "total %s,%s\n", $1, $2}`

This uses `printf` instead of `print` where the first argument defines the format.

`%s,%s` tells it to print the values of `$1` and `$2` delimited by a comma and the `\n` represents a new line so that it moves to the next line and prints the values of `$1` and `$2` until the end of the file.

Personally, I would use the second command with `printf` as you can just use one set of quotes instead of quoting both `total` and the comma. It is also more modular as you'll find from reading its man page. I'm only including the two commands to show the two different ways.

The output

```
title
total AAA,111
total BBB,222
total CCC,333
end
```

Comment: If you're using `awk` to do the parsing of the file, then use `awk` to do _all_ the parsing of the file.  It doesn't make sense to call `awk` for each individual line when you could do `awk 'BEGIN { print "title" } { printf("total %s,%s\n", $1,$2) } END { print "end" }' list`

Comment: @Kusalananda I would actually make that an answer as it entirely eliminates the need for the `for` loop.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from adding it to your already existing answer :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for your help! Let me know if there's anything in there where I've made a mistake or if it can be explained better.

Comment: thanks @Kusalananda, Nasir.. given awk method works, i have choosen to go for while method.

Answer (score 1):

While your specific problem is much better addressed by using a text processing utility [like `awk` as shown by @Nasir](/a/507337) (see also [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)), I'll answer the question in the title.

The `for i j in words...; do something with $i and $j; done` is `zsh` syntax, not supported by `bash` yet.

Also `bash` performs both splitting (which you want) and globbing (which you don't want) upon `` `cmd` `` (the obsolete form of command substitution, you may want to switch to `$(cmd)`), while `zsh` only does splitting as you'd expect.

To process two words at a time with `bash` or other POSIX-like shells, instead of `for i j in words...`, you can do:

```
set -- words...
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  i=$1 j=$2 # or j=${2-missing}
  something with "$i" and "$j"
  shift "$(( 2 - ($# == 1) ))"
done
```

In your case, the `set` would look like:

```
set -o noglob # disable globbing
set -- $(cat list)
```

(assumes an unmodified `$IFS` which by default contains space, tab and newline).